# Check if psycopg2 client is LISTEN'ing to topics

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

I'm looking for any way to check on the server or on the client whether a client is listening on a specific NOTIFY topic.

There used to be a `pg_listener` table in PostgreSQL versions up to 8.x (https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/catalog-pg-listener.html).

In modern Postgres versions, I can't find anything on the client or server side that shows any information about active LISTENs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `pg_listening_channels()` table function from PostgreSQL 9.0 on:

```
SELECT * FROM pg_listening_channels();
```

Comment: That seems to work exactly like I need it to, thanks a lot! There's not an awful lot of documentation around it :/

Comment: I found it trawling the Git log messages of PostgreSQL.